# "You iron clothes if they are […]"

Tags: word-request, adjectives

> These jeans are […], you need to iron it.

> After the washing machine, the clothes are […]. You have to iron them.

What adjective would you fill in the gaps with? My dictionary gives me *wrinkled*, *creased*, *rumpled*, and *crumpled*.

Comment: Those are all possible candidates. I might steer clear of _crease_, because, with clothing (and pants in particular), a _crease_ often refers to a deliberate crease, as seen [here](http://www.magnificentbastard.com/images/pics/dockers-creased.jpg).

Comment: Side note: In English, jeans are plural: "These jeans are wrinkled: you need to iron THEM." We speak of a "pair of jeans", as if each leg was a separate thing. I don't think it makes sense but that's how it is. :-)

Comment: @J.R. I would say *creased* is the most apporpriate answer. I agree that the crease in a trouser leg is meant to be there, but creases are what irons remove.

Comment: @MattEllen: Or what irons are supposed to put in...

Comment: @Matt: Superficially, [**creased** trousers](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wrinkled+trousers%2Ccrumpled+trousers%2Ccreased+trousers&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) appears to have the edge. But if you examine the results, I think you'll agree this is because most of the usages involve ***positive*** references to "sharp" crease lines deliberately created by ironing. That's why I chose to chart ***shirt*** in my answer (you still get "sharply-creased shirts" in a good sense, but not so much as to distort the graph excessively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a lot of regional variation on this one, but [here's the overall picture](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wrinkled+shirt%2Ccrumpled+shirt%2Ccreased+shirt&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image]

I won't bother adding more charts, but if you follow the link above, and toggle between US/UK corpuses, you'll see that Brits still favour ***crumpled***, but Americans have moved decisively in favour of *wrinkled* over recent decades. By weight of numbers ***wrinkled*** is definitely the one with the most promising future.

---

In the context of clothes, *wrinkled, crumpled, creased, rumpled,* etc. all mean exactly the same thing. But note that trousers, for example, may occasionally be approvingly referred to as [nicely creased](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22nicely%20creased%20trousers%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) when they've been ironed/pressed to make a sharp fold line exactly where it's wanted.

Comment: As far as I know, a [ruffled shirt](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruffled+shirt) is a pirate shirt.

Comment: @Kobi: As far as I know, that's just the linguistically-challenged person's version of a [**ruffed** shirt](http://bbprivateer.ca/?q=node/158) :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean - am I supposed to be insulted by that? Either way, what is "ruffed" in this context?

Comment: @Kobi: No insult intended. A "ruff" is [a stiffly starched frilled or pleated circular collar of lace, muslin, or other fine fabric, worn by men and women in the 16th and 17th centuries.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ruff) Such "ruffs" can be around the neck and/or the wrists (as in the archetypal pirate's shirt). I suppose when it's [an entire loose section across the front of the garment](http://www1.macys.com/cms/slp/2/Ruffle-Shirt) you could call it a "ruffled shirt" for want of a better term, but I wouldn't think it's really the same thing.

Comment: A ruffled shirt is a shirt that has [ruffles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffle): strips of fabric that have been gathered and sewn in place. A ruffle is a design element, and a shirt that has them is supposed to have them. It is **not** the same thing as a wrinkled (rumpled, whatever) shirt—in fact, ironing a ruffle would probably be a serious mistake.

Comment: @phenry: I shouldn't have included *ruffled* in the chart in the first place - it was never really relevant to OP's context. I've no problem with [he pulled a ruffled handkerchief from the pockets of his pants to wipe the dirt from his hands](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22ruffled+handkerchief+from+the%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which I understand to be a *crumpled* hankie, not one with a "by design" ruffled edge. But it's not normally used of things like clothes fresh from the spin dryer.

Comment: Fair enough--although it should also be noted that "rumpled" beats "crumpled" since about 1980: http://goo.gl/Yzdho

Comment: @phenry: Well, they always say if you wait long enough, the old-fashioned stuff will eventually become fashionable again.

Comment: My wardrobe depends on it.

Answer (score 9):

Based on Skymninge's response, there may be some UK/US difference here.

In the US, the word you are looking for would clearly be "wrinkled". In general:

"Wrinkled" means having undesired, unordered lines, folds, or ridges in the material.

"Crumpled" means not neatly folded or hung, like if you just threw them on the floor.

"Creased" can refer to any folds or ridges in the material, but is usually used to refer to a desired ridge. On pants, that would be the creases down the front and back of the legs.

"Rumpled" is generally irregular and untidy. I think it's a somewhat out-of-date word.

Answer (score 3):

*Wrinkled* is more used for wrinkles on skin, *crumpled* is used for "crumpled look" clothing (clothes that are meant to look unironed), so this is the one you're searching for.

Comment: If the pants are not meant to look crumpled. But they are after careless treat. Can I say "Do you go to school in those pants? Look, they are all crumpled!" ?

Comment: This is what I would say, yes.

Comment: This might be a regional thing. Here in the U.S., I'd use _wrinkled_. As you can see from this [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wrinkled+clothes%2Ccrumpled+clothes%2Cwrinkled+jeans%2Ccrumpled+jeans&year_start=1930&year_end=1985&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), there's no real "right" answer to this question. (As a side note, though, if you change the Ngram corpus to British English, the result will say, "Ngrams not found: wrinkled jeans".

Comment: Trousers get crumpled and need to be ironed, pants get wrinkled and need to be ironed. Well, American pants do; English pants go under the trousers.